# Consuming more than one model using RabbitMQ RPC

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rpc

I just implemented an application using RabbitMQ RPC.
I need to call multiple methods and consume the results of them. So, created generic classes and methods to reach my goal.

**The main problem is:** My client side consumer, consumes every response more than one time, because this consumer listen to just one queue ('*amq.rabbitmq.reply-to*' or any named queue), but I have to add consumer for my every model.

I could handle this problem using *CorrelationId* property of messages, but the problem will become more serious when I have lots of models to consume.
At first I followed the official sample of RabbitMQ, then implemented [this](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-website/issues/601) approach, and now I'm using Direct Reply-to approach.

This is how I implement my consumer:

```
RpcClient.consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    if (!_callbackMapper.TryRemove(ea.BasicProperties.CorrelationId, out TaskCompletionSource<TResponse> tcs))
        return;
    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
    var response = body.FromByteArray<TResponse>();
    tcs.TrySetResult(response);
};
```

This code snippet runs just one time for every model.
**Note:** This code snippet must not run just one time, because it will listen just to one model.